# How implement an infinity list in a combobox with int values

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, win-universal-app

I want to implement a dynamic combobox what contain int values and its dynamically load new elements before the user is reaching the end of the list.

So for example I load the list with the initial value of 15 and the list initially contains +- 5 element and when user reach the +- 3. element from the end of the list then its add five more element respectively to the end or the beginning.

How can I archive this?

Comment: have you tried something or not?

Comment: I don't have any exact idea how to do it. I am kind of new to C# XAML, but I am not looking only for a ready to use solution. Some article could be enough to point me in the right direction. My initial idea was to simply make bind a 15 element list to the combo box and simply rearrange the elments in it but this method has 2 problem. First I dont know what elements are visible in the list, secondly if I change the array under it the list will "jump". (This is only my theory, I havent tried anything yet)

Answer (score 2):

To do that, you need to handler the `ScrollChanged` event of the `scrollViwer` control inside the `Combobox`'s `ControlTemplate`.

First, edit the `combobox` Template: from visual studio designer selecte > **Edit template** > **Edit a Copy**,

[image]

In the generated style search for `DropDownScrollViewer` and add a `ScrollChanged` event handler

## XAML

```
//..
 <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer" ScrollChanged="OnScrollChanged">
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
 //..
```

Now, let say your `combobox` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` like this :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CbBox" ItemsSource="{Binding CboxItems}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}"/>
```

## ViewModel

```
 private ObservableCollection<string> _cboxItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
    };        
    public ObservableCollection<string> CboxItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _cboxItemsCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_cboxItemsCollection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _cboxItemsCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

## Handler

the handler should look like that:

```
private void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
     if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          {
             CboxItems.Add((CboxItems.Count+i).ToString());
          }
       }
  }
```

**EDIT**

i forgot to mention about the scroll to top, following the same principle when the `VerticalOffset` of the `scrollViewer` is equal to 0, insert the negative items at the top of the collection:

```
//..
        if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0)
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                CboxItems.Insert(0,"negaive item");
            }
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(10);
         }
        //..
```

the `scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(10);` is to prevent the infinite loop since by default the `scrollViewer` always scroll to the top.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! I will check it out and report back with the result.